# Binary Process Tree with fork()

Tags: c, fork, binary-tree

My first project for my OS class is to create a process tree using `fork()` that has a depth that the user specifies at the command line. Each leaf level node needs to sort data and pass it back to its parent using named-pipes (FIFOs).

I can create an N-depth tree with `fork()`, each process having 2 children. What I can’t figure out is how to pass a FIFO to each child all the way down the tree and then have this *process* perform a sort on certain data in the FIFO *and then* also pass it back up the tree to the top.

Here is the pseudo-code of what I have so far for building the tree:

```
void CreateTree(int level)
{
    if level = 0 return

    int left_child = fork();
    if(left_child != 0)        //we are the parent
    {
        int right_child = fork();
        if(right_child == 0)
            CreateTree(level - 1);
    }
    else
    {
        CreateTree(level-1);
    }
}
```

So how do I grab each process individually to do work with them?

Comment: that's a far better assignment that you get at most cs programs

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned fifo, aka a named pipe, so we'll look at that. (code here assumes *nix):

This quick example shows sending data from the parent to the child, having the child manipulate it, then returning it to the parent. So you're not "passing" the fifo, but each process (or child process) will have access to the `char *` which gives them the name of the fifo so they can open it for reading or writting as they need to. You can take this concept and expand upon it for each of the children nodes you have:

```
int main()
{
    int fd, n, ret;
    fd_set rfds;
    char * myfifo = "/tmp/myfifo";

    mkfifo(myfifo, 0666);  // Create this buffer

    if(fork())     //Kid code
    {
      char kid_buffer[4] = {0};
      char temp;

      fd = open(myfifo, O_RDONLY); //Open the fifo for reading
      n = read(fd, kid_buffer, 4);

      printf("Kid %d read %d bytes, parent gave us %s\n",getpid(), n, kid_buffer);
      fflush(stdout);
      close(fd);

      // "sort" the data the parent gave us
      temp = kid_buffer[0];
      kid_buffer[0] = kid_buffer[1];
      kid_buffer[1] = kid_buffer[2];
      kid_buffer[2] = temp;
      kid_buffer[3] = '\0';
      printf("Kid %d reoriginized the list %s\n",getpid(), kid_buffer);
      fflush(stdout);

      // send the data back
      fd = open(myfifo, O_WRONLY);
      write(fd, kid_buffer, strlen(kid_buffer));
      close(fd);
      return 0; 
    }
    else
    {
      char arr[] = "abc";

      //Open the fifo for writing
      fd = open(myfifo, O_WRONLY);
      write(fd, arr, strlen(arr));  //Sent my data to kid
      printf("Parent process %d, just sent my data %s to the kid\n", getpid(), arr);
      fflush(stdout);
      close(fd);

      //Open the fifo for reading
      fd = open(myfifo, O_RDONLY);
      n = read(fd, arr, 4);

      // show the data we got back
      printf("Parent %d read %d bytes, kid gave us back %s\n",getpid(), n, arr);
      fflush(stdout);
      close(fd);
    }

    unlink(myfifo);

    return 0;
}
```

So from the output here you can see the parent created it's own array "abc" and it got modified by the child (passed via FIFO) to "bca", now it's back with the parent and formated.

```
mike@linux-4puc:~> ./a.out 
Parent process 4295, just sent my data abc to the kid
Kid 4294 read 3 bytes, parent gave us abc
Kid 4294 reoriginized the list bca
Parent 4295 read 3 bytes, kid gave us back bca
```

Comment: The IPC mechanism has been specified; they're using named pipes.

Comment: I understand what you've written and thanks for that. But I'm wondering, do I have to do all of the sorting of data at the time of the fork()s or is there a way to access these processes later on?

Comment: @ZachKauffman - The second you call `fork()` the new processes start running "concurrently" (as best the system can), so you have to give the processes something to do. If you want them to "sit and wait" until they're called upon you have to have a method to do so. For example in the way I called my code above `read()` will block forever until there's something on the FIFO. However in my example with just 1 child there's only 1 FIFO. If you have more then one child and they're listening to the same FIFO there's no guarantee that they'll wake up in the order you want.

Comment: @ZachKauffman - One way to handle what you are trying to do is have more then one FIFO and associate each child with a specific FIFO. You'll have to keep track of all the PIDs and associate each one with one FIFO.  Have all the children call `read()` to block them and then once they're all created have the parent `open()` and `write()` to each FIFO handle in the order you want the children to run. Does that help?

Answer (score 1):

You did not state any dataflow requirements such as the source of the data that the leaves are to sort. In terms of division of labor, the leaf nodes will sort, but the branches need only merge. In some sense, you are creating a hybrid [mergesort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) that uses processes and FIFOs instead of the stack.

As stated, you could use the simple but inelegant approach of allocating an array of values to be sorted and creating all FIFOs up front in the main process. Based on each child’s identifier or index number, it would select a range of data from the overall array and the appropriate FIFO (say, `fifo.N` for the FIFO that node *N* uses to transmit data to its parent). Recall that a child process created with `fork` shares its parent’s address space and can see an array at global scope, for example.

A binary tree packs nicely into an array. According to [Binary tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#Arrays) on Wikipedia

> Binary trees can also be stored in breadth-first order as an implicit data structure in arrays, and if the tree is a complete binary tree, this method wastes no space. In this compact arrangement, if a node has an index *i*, its children are found at indices *2i+1* (for the left child) and *2i+2* (for the right), while its parent (if any) is found at index ⌊*(i-1)/2*⌋ (assuming the root has index zero).

Note that ⌊*x*⌋ is the greatest integer not greater than *x*, also known as the [floor of *x*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions). In C, you can get the floor by assigning the value of `(i-1)/2` to a variable of type `int`.

To thread node identifiers around your tree, you could use code such as

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

void proc_tree(int i, int current_depth, int max_depth)
{
  pid_t kid = fork();

  if (kid == -1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "[%d]: fork: %s\n", getpid(), strerror(errno));
  }
  else if (kid == 0) {
    /* child */
    printf("[%d]: i=%d (depth %d)\n", getpid(), i, current_depth);

    if (current_depth < max_depth) {
      proc_tree(2*i+1, current_depth+1, max_depth);
      proc_tree(2*i+2, current_depth+1, max_depth);
    }

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
  }
  else {
    /* parent */
    pid_t pid;
    int status;
    pid = waitpid(kid, &status, 0);
    if (pid == -1)
      fprintf(stderr, "[%z]: waitpid: %s\n", getpid(), strerror(errno));
  }
}
```

Invoke it with

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int depth;

  if (argc != 2) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s depth\n", argv[0]);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  depth = atoi(argv[1]);
  if (depth < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s: depth must be non-negative\n", argv[0]);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  proc_tree(0, 0, depth);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Sample output:

```
$ ./tree-sort 3
[28837]: i=0 (depth 0)
[28838]: i=1 (depth 1)
[28839]: i=3 (depth 2)
[28840]: i=7 (depth 3)
[28841]: i=8 (depth 3)
[28842]: i=4 (depth 2)
[28843]: i=9 (depth 3)
[28844]: i=10 (depth 3)
[28845]: i=2 (depth 1)
[28846]: i=5 (depth 2)
[28847]: i=11 (depth 3)
[28848]: i=12 (depth 3)
[28849]: i=6 (depth 2)
[28850]: i=13 (depth 3)
[28851]: i=14 (depth 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

- Allocate a number to each child (not the PID; you need to know the number before there is a PID!).
- Create a FIFO (`mkfifo()`) with a name such as `fifo.N` where N is the number.
- Each child then knows which FIFO it is to write to.
- Each parent knows which FIFOs it is to read from.  (Presumably, the parents are just running a merge rather than a sort.)

Presumably, the children all know, somehow, what data they have to sort, too.

---

> After I initialize all my FIFOs, how do I then know which process is executing and when? When I am back in my main program after I build the tree, is there any way to sort out which process is running based on PIDs and control statements?

Processes can be divided into 'leaf' and 'non-leaf' processes.

Leaf processes don't have any children.  They do their sorting assignment and write the sorted data to their output FIFO.  They'll be blocked on the FIFO until their parent process opens it for reading.  When they are done writing, they close the FIFO and the parent process gets EOF.

Each non-leaf process is merging the sorted data from its two children.  Each non-leaf process needs to know what its own output FIFO is (root node probably writes to standard output rather than a FIFO), and what its two children's FIFOs are.  Maybe the non-leaf process creates fifo.$$.1 and fifo.$$.2 (where '$$' is the PID of the non-leaf process that is already running), rather than having the parent create them all up front.  Then it forks its two children, with a variable indicating to each child which FIFO to use.  The non-leaf process then opens the two FIFOs for reading (and its own output FIFO for writing), and does a merge of the two data streams (reading a line from both, writing the smaller to the output, reading a replacement line, and keeping going until EOF on one, then finishing the reading from the other).  Once it has done, the process deletes the two FIFOs it created (basic hygiene) and closes its output FIFO and exits.

At the top-level (original process), the basic mechanism is the same as any non-leaf process; it creates two FIFOs, starts the two children, opens the FIFOs for reading, does a merge on the two streams, writing to standard output instead of needing to mess with another FIFO.

Comment: So I guess my question would then be (after I initialize all my FIFOs), how do I then know which process is executing and when? When I am back in my main program after I build the tree, is there any way to sort out which process is running based on PIDs and control statements?