# Binary proccessing tree gives wrong results

Tags: c, fork

I have to make a binary proccessing tree to sort some records but i've got stuck at the creation.
I am using this recursive code to product a binary tree of proccesses:

```
void proc_tree(int i, int current_depth, int max_depth, int rec, int offset)
{
  pid_t kid = fork();

  if(kid == 0)
  {
    printf("[%d,%d]: start: %d, end: %d\n", i, current_depth, rec, offset);

    if(current_depth < max_depth)
    {
      int nodes= pow(2, current_depth);

      if(i >= nodes)
       i = 0;

      proc_tree(2*i+1, current_depth+1, max_depth, rec, offset/2);
      proc_tree(2*i+1, current_depth+1, max_depth, offset/2, offset);
    }
   }
}
```

I have not included any error checking i am doing and i haven't included the code of the father since the only thing he is doing atm is to wait for the children to end.

The output i am getting is this:

```
[0,0]: start: 0, end: 180
[1,1]: start: 0, end: 90
[3,2]: start: 0, end: 45
[4,2]: start: 46, end: 90
[2,1]: start: 91, end: 180
[1,2]: start: 91, end: 90
[2,2]: start: 91, end: 180
```

As you can see most of the values are fine but at depth = 2 the first node ([1,2]) and ([2,2]) have wrong values. Since we got a total of 181 records at depth = 2 there are 4 nodes so each node should be managing about 45 records each. So [1,2] should be 91, 136
and [2,2] should be 137, 180.

I am calling the function from main like this

```
proc_tree(0, 0, 2, 0, 180);
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You do realise that `fork` creates a new process and each process has its own copy of the memory.

Also the OS is free to process in any order as it sees fit.

I guess you are thinking of recursion. In which case you do not need fork.

Comment: Yeah i know that fork creates a copy of the address memory of the parent. I am asked to create a binary proccessing tree for an assignment and i found this solution on the internet because i couldn't figure out how to make that work properly...But this doesn't work either. And i wasn't worried about the ordering of the results since i am familiar with time scheduling, at least the basics. In fact this was the link with the suggestion http://stackoverflow.com/a/13038661/2212484

Comment: Despite the ordering of the output at depth 2 the proccesses should have 0,45--46,90--91,136--137,80. At least that should be the case, i don't know if i miss anything here but since i call the function with those parameters and fork is called inside that function then the values printed shouldn't be those that i am getting(well i guess they should since i am getting them, i just can't figure out why). And i didn't want to sound like an ass...I am just too tired struggling with this task.